# How can I melt two rows of a data.table into one by keeping only two column values of one of the rows and then deleting it

Tags: r, data.table

I have two rows, but I only need one of them, so I want to take two of the column values of the row I want to delete and replace them at the other row,
For exp:

| column1 | column2 | column3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 3 | 4 |
| 5 | 6 | 4 |

I want to get

| column1 | column2 | column3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 5 | 3 | 4 |

I tried this but this doesnt quiet work and its a bit messy

```
merge_rows <- function(dt, column, condition_column, condition){
  # Find duplicate rows based on column
  duplicate_rows <- dt[, .(duplicate = anyDuplicated(get(column))), by = column]
  duplicate_rows <- duplicate_rows[duplicate > 0,]
  # For each duplicate row
  for(i in 1:nrow(duplicate_rows)){
    # Get the index of the duplicate row
    duplicate_index <- which(dt[,get(column)] == duplicate_rows[i,get(column)])
    # Select the columns to keep
    selected_columns <- dt[duplicate_index[1],c("column1", "column2")]
    # Delete the duplicate row based on the condition
    if(dt[duplicate_index[1],get(condition_column)] == condition){
        dt[duplicate_index[2],] <- NULL
    }else{
        dt[duplicate_index[1],] <- NULL
    }
    # Assign the selected columns to the remaining row
    dt[duplicate_index[1], c("column1", "column2") := selected_columns]
  }
  return(dt)
}
```

Comment: How do you determine which rows are duplicates? In the data provided there's no clear way to programmatically do what you want.

Comment: yes you are right, I changed column 3, having now two values that are equal